# where to implement setUserIdentifier function from crashlytics in swift

Tags: swift, crashlytics, userid

I am new to swift. 
I am now trying to implement crashlytics in to my app.
I have followed the tutorial to implement it for basic report but I want to implement userID so that I know who has problem using my app.
I have checked online and found setUserIdentifier function but I have no idea where to implement this function.
Do I need to call this function in every page or in app delegate.swift?
Please give me an example on how to implement this one function.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I checked that one and it was too old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 let phoneID = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor.UUIDString
 Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])
 Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserIdentifier(phoneID)
```

I used this to solve the problem and get the phone id.

Comment: Using the UUID will likely get your app **rejected** during an AppStore review. Here are some [alternatives](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/04/unique-identifiers/)

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly discourage the @Jun-Luo 's approach of using UUUID.

```
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserIdentifier("12345")
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserEmail("mail@domain.com")
Crashlytics.sharedInstance().setUserName("AppUserName")
```

You can use any one of above to track the user. But its better to secure user privacy, hence all we need as a developer is a **ID** which we can easily tack back with our server side access.

[Code Example](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/features)

https://docs.fabric.io/apple/crashlytics/enhanced-reports.html

Comment: I integrated Crashlytics for my application! but failed to set value for setUserIdentifier('12345').  where do i find this UserIdentifier value?

Comment: @kiran : AppDelegate is the place to do ur SDKs setup. Add the above code in ur didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

Comment: my question is where to find the value of userIdentifier value.   This 12345 value ->  where to find?

Comment: @kiran : that is up to your application-specific question, each app handles how it stores user information. The "12345" in this case is just an example code. In your application, you should replace it with the actual user id that has logged into your app.

Comment: @kiran Use your user's userId from backend API.